# Is given IP address assigned to some Wi-Fi Hotspot?

Tags: networking, dataset, ip, wifi

I'm doing a project: the goal is to find features detecting a hotspot, but I have no training set or test set for development and estimation of methods yet.

As far as I understand, there are 2 ways to build the sets:

- to get a list of some of U.S. hotspots;
- to find a function that checks if given IP address is connected with some hotspot (with some measure of certainty).

So what I wonder:

- is there any U.S. Hotspots IP dataset?
- are there any other ways or technologies to find out whether a given IP address is assigned to a Hotspot?

Any helpful ideas appreciated (criticism is appreciated too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips.

1. You actually want to use MAC address, not IP. IPs can change quite a bit easier than MAC addresses.
2. There are at least 2 sets of mac/location data sets, Skyhook and Google. [Skyhook](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/location-technology/support.php) has a web site where you can learn more about their SDK, I don't think Google allows direct access of their. The cost to use Skyhook varies, but in general it is around $0.50 a device, depending on a large number of factors.

Comment: 1. Sadly, I have data with IP + 'user activity' time.
2. Many thanks for the links.